# problem with a viewport scrolling based animation in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<script>
function changeOpacityGradually() {
    const cover = document.getElementById('SecondSect_cover');

    let opacity = 0;
    const interval = 0.003;
    const duration = 1800;
    const frames = duration / (interval * 1000);

    function animate() {
        opacity -= interval;
        cover.style.filter = `opacity(${opacity})`;

        if (opacity > 0) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
    }

    return animate;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const animateOpacity = changeOpacityGradually();
    const secondSection = document.getElementById('SecondSect');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        const rect = secondSection.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.top <= window.innerHeight && rect.bottom >= 0) {
            animateOpacity();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<template>
    <section id="SecondSect">
        <div id="SecondSect_cover"></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit pariatur rem facilis aut maxime deleniti
            eveniet, expedita distinctio modi culpa voluptatum minima possimus animi magni.</p>
    </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
#SecondSect {
    background-image: url('../../assets/images/backgrounds/bg_3.png');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

#SecondSect_cover {
    background-image: url('../../assets/images/backgrounds/bg_3.png');
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    filter: opacity(1);
}
</style>
```

I would like that when the user's viewport is in the SecondSect, an animation starts that gradually changes the filter of the #SecondSect_cover from opacity: 1 to opacity: 0
With the code I wrote, I don't have any errors, however as soon as I log in, the style remains opacity:1 and when I scroll to the affected section, nothing happens.

Comment: vuejs has some easy to use [animation functionality](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/animation.html). Try using that instead of directly manipulating the DOM